# Ramanand Sagar's Krishna

Tags: krishna, yadavas

I am currently watching Ramanand Sagar's Krishna and I noticed some unseen and unheard details in the serial. For instance, Rohini, Vasudev's first wife was secretly taken out of Mathura to Nand's village by the Yadav leaders. Also, another detail that was shown was that Devakis's first son Kirtiman was born outside prison and was killed outside prison. How much of this detail is canonical ?

Comment: Not a proper answer but a quick comment, I think that most of the serials that are made are for entertainment and are created without much research. However, Ramanand Sagar is different, He keeps saying that whatever his shows depict are mentioned in the books, So if this show is uncovering such details, it possibly means they are present in the primary books (Bhagwat Puran in this case), we are just now aware about them.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal I understand. I just wanted to see if anyone can find some citations from the text to ensure that this is the case.